# How to change layout?

Tags: android, layout

So I've just started trying to learn android code and as a first experiement i wanted to add 2 windows/layouts and a way to get from one to the other, I thought 2 addon would do the trick.

So basiclly I start in activity_my, and when I press the button which is in this UI I get to my 2nd layout called layout2, however when I try and get back to my original one nothing happens.. why?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
int k =0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        final ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        EditText phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneNUMBER);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
            k=1;

        }
    });

    if(k==1){
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                k=0;
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Either you use 2 Fragments in one Activity or use a separate Activity and Intent from there.

Comment: Are you trying to switch between activities?

Comment: you have to use the View switcher for switching the views you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one layout and one activity. you have to just hide/show your layout on button click.i have implemented it.You can try below code.may be it will help you.

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="layout 1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="layout 1" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="layout 2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="layout 2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

Button btn1, btn2;
LinearLayout layout1, layout2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    layout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    layout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout2);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            layout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            layout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            layout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            layout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });

}

}
```